# Utilizing Workflow to Automatically Resolve a Case in Microsoft CRM (No User Input)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a logic question regarding the capabilities of automatically resolving Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM (or similar platforms) cases. I utilize an Access database to create emails to send to customers with specific data, while copying my team email to keep track of communications in Microsoft CRM. This action creates a new case in my CRM, which I then need to "Work On" case, add my specific operational catalogs and affected contacts, then finish case as Resolved just to ensure tracking in the CRM system.

My team is currently testing out the capabilities of XML coding in the email which allows the CRM to automatically capture the case specifics described above, however they still need to go in and resolve each case at the end of the day.

After some research, I see that a workflow may be able to do this job of automatically Resolving cases. Is this a possible function for a workflow or plugin to do? Alternatively I have been told by my IT department that we need to have a robot built to complete this task, but I would like to keep this as efficient (and cost savvy) as possible. Any input or suggestions are greatly valued and appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve your problem.

1. If you want to close all the "CASES" by the day end you can schedule 
   a "System Workflow" that will execute daily at a specific time and
   "Close/Resolve" all the open CASES in your system. Please find below 
   link on how to setup a "Schedule Workflow" in Dynamics CRM  [Create

   Recursive or Scheduled Workflows in CRM](https://www.powerobjects.com/2012/11/09/create-recursive-or-scheduled-workflows-in-crm/)
2. You can resolve specific cases on Dynamics CRM using C#. Please find below link on how to resolve case using C#.[How to close cases in crm 2011 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175479/how-to-close-cases-in-crm-2011-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Workflows can be used to close Case records in CRM

[image: Close Case]

If you have the resources (staff) available to write CRM code, you can do it via Code (C#) as well